# Vue2: How to work with JSONP?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to set up a callback with JSONP but I am unsure how to set it up correctly in Vue. Can someone provide a little guidance?

**My current test gets me back the data as 'undefined'. How can I get my post title to appear?**

Here's how I have it set up.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/z2m1hukL/

My Vue instance:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    thePosts: []
  },
  created: function(){
    $.getScript('https://demo.wp-api.org/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&_jsonp=receiveData')
        .done(receiveData())
        .fail(function(){
            console.log('there was an error.');
        })
  }
});
```

My JSONP callback function is linked as a `<script>`in the HEAD and contains the
following:

```
function receiveData( data ) {
  // Do something with the data here.
  // For demonstration purposes, we'll simply log it.
  console.log( data );
  this.thePosts = data;
}
```

View/HTML:

```
<div id="app" style="margin-top: 5em;">

  <article v-for="post in thePosts">
    <h2 v-html="post.title.rendered"></h2>
  </article>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery, which makes Vue largely irrelevent.

Use `$.ajax` to make JSONP requests with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
      // Use the JSONP data type to stop it using XHR
      dataType: "jsonp",
      // Pass the URL without the query string
      url: 'https://demo.wp-api.org/',
      // Use data to provide the query string information
      data: {
          rest_route: "/wp/v2/posts"
      },
      // Specify the callback argument NAME with jsonp
      jsonp: "_jsonp" 
 })
    // Pass the _function_ you want to handle the response with to `done`. Don't call it immediately and pass the return value
    .done(receiveData) 
    .fail(function(){
        console.log('there was an error.');
    })
```

As for `recieveData`:

> ```
> function receiveData( data ) {
>   // Do something with the data here.
>   // For demonstration purposes, we'll simply log it.
>   console.log( data );
>   this.thePosts = data;
> }
> ```

`this` will not hold the value you want it to be. I don't know what value you want there, but you should use that instead.

Comment: Thank you. It wouldn't work unless I changed `this.thePosts` in the callback to `vm.thePosts`.